# Chef-solo: how can I install a package mailutils in ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, chef-solo

I want to install the command line `mail` in my ubuntu box in Virtual box.

The command line will be `sudo apt-get install mailutils`.

What is the best to achieve the same via chef-solo? I don't think there is a formula called `mailutils`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use simple recipe like this:

it have to be located in your cookbook recipes/default.rb file

```
package 'mailutils' do
  action :install
end
```